# how Format price value in inputbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

I am working on a site, it has a input field for price. i need to format the price value something like the following.

```
if a user enter "1000000" it should replace with "1,000,000" is it possible?
```

Any help?

Comment: You need to use an input mask. Are you using any libraries?

Comment: OP, look at the most upvoted answer in the question I link to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need custom function like this :

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Comment: **Thank you** its working fine. i just finished one of my project.. once agin thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following:

```
function numberWithCommas(n) {
    var parts=n.toString().split(".");
    return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/e9AeK/

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification to the code of **Taiki**.
Because if user enter **1000000** it will produce **1,000,000**. but if the user use **Backspace** key to remove "0" it will not work.

```
function addPriceFormat()
{
    var numb='';
    nStr = document.getElementById('txt').value;
    my = nStr.split(',');
    var Len = my.length;
    for (var i=0; i<Len;i++){numb = numb+my[i];}
    x = numb.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

    while (rgx.test(x1)) 
    {
       x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    formated = x1 + x2;
    document.getElementById('txt').value = formated;
}
```